# Sscanf doesn't give me a value

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I have this piece of code:

```
if(string_starts_with(line, "name: ") == 0){
    //6th is the first char of the name
    char name[30];
    int count = 6;
    while(line[count] != '\0'){
        name[count-6] = line[count];
        ++count;
    }
    printf("custom string name: %s", name);
    strncpy(p.name, name, 30);
}
else if(string_starts_with(line, "age: ") == 0){
    //6th is the first char of the name
    printf("age line: %s", line);
    short age = 0;
    sscanf(line, "%d", age);
    printf("custom age: %d\n", age);
}
```

The `if` works, but the `else if` doesn't work.
Example output is:

```
person:
name: great
custom string name: great
age: 6000
age line: age: 6000
custom age: 0
```

I have changed a lot, like using `&age` in the `sscanf` function, but nothing works.

Comment: I'm very sure the `else` does also work. It is the condition which does not work. Please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @GilianJoosen  He means type of `line` .

Comment: How ie `line` declared ? We've seen thing here, you wouldn't imagine.

Comment: line is:     char line[200];

Comment: please, provide full code

Answer (score 6):

If you want to store a value into a `short` (why¿?) you need to use an appropriate length modifier. Also, if you are expecting the number to come after the prefix string, you need to start the scan after the prefix string. Finally, as you mention in passing, it is necessary to give `sscanf` the *address* of the variable in which you want to store the value.

And remember to check the return value of `sscanf` to make sure you found a number.

In short:

```
if (sscanf(line + 5, "%hd", &age) != 1) {
  /* handle the error */
}
```

Several of these errors (but not all of them) would have been shown if you had compiled with extra warnings enabled. With gcc or clang, always use `-Wall` in your compiler options.

Comment: @GilianJoosen: You could have used that in your handling of `name` as well. There's no need to make a copy of `line`; you could just refer to `line + 6`, although it would be better to find the first non-whitespace character after the colon,.

Answer (score 1):

```
short age = 0;
sscanf(line, "%d", age);
```

`age` is of type `short` and format specifier you used is `%d` which is wrong.

Use `%hd` for `short` instead-

```
  sscanf(line+5, "%hd",&age);
```